# Excel coding Sheets(1).Range("A11").EntireRow.Insert

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some code that will insert a new line on Worksheet 1 whenever a new worksheet is copied. I would also like the code to make cells on the new line reference certain cells from the newly copied sheet.

The problem I have is that my code is inserting 3 lines instead of 1 and the cell D11 only shows gets the text copied from Sheet2 instead of being equal.

Hope that all makes sense. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Sheets(1).Range("A11").EntireRow.Insert
  Sheets(1).Range("D11").Formula = Sheets(2).Range("C10")
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome Scot! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: "whenever a new worksheet is copied" - needs a bit more detail around this....  Where is the sheet copied from, and where is it copied to?  Is the user copying the sheet, or are you doing that via code?

Comment: Alright ... I have found the reason for it adding three lines. It's do to the Sheet activate function. Is there another function i can use to detect a copied Worksheet?

Comment: Hi Tim,  I have a Worksheet that is an order template, I want to be able to right click and make a copy that I can fill out so that each order has it's own worksheet. So the worksheet is just being copied and placed right beside it within the workbook